# Get instances from intersection

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following list of tags:

```
List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag> {
  new Tag { Name = "Book", Slug = "book" },
  new Tag { Name = "Travel", Slug = "travel" } 
}
```

And I have a list of posts where each post has a few tags:

```
List<Post> model = new List<Post> {
  new Post {
    Title = "First Post",
    Tags = new List<Tag> { 
      new Tag { Name = "Book", Slug = "book" },
      new Tag { Name = "Europe", Slug = "europe" } 
    },
  },
  new Post {
    Title = "Second Post",
    Tags = new List<Tag> { 
      new Tag { Name = "Travel", Slug = "travel" },
      new Tag { Name = "Europe", Slug = "europe" } 
    }
  }
};
```

For each post I need to redefine the tags, base on slug, with the instances in tags.

The first post has two tags with the following slugs `book` and `europe`.

I need to get from `tags` the first one because it has the slug `book`existent in Post's Tags.

Then the Post Tags property will be:

```
List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag> {
  tags[0]
}
```

So I need to use the instance on tags.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove tags which are not in the `tags` list (based on `Slug` property) and to replace the `Tag` instances by the ones declared in `tags` variable, you can do this :

```cs
foreach (var post in model)
{
    post.Tags = tags.Where(t => post.Tags.Any(u => u.Slug == t.Slug)).ToList();
}
```

This doesn't create new `Post` instances like in @Sajid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to create a `IEqualityComparer<Tag>` class:

```
public class TagEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Tag>
{
    public bool Equals(Tag x, Tag y)
    {
        return x.Slug == y.Slug;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Tag obj)
    {
        return obj.Slug.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then pass this comparer to [`Enumerable.Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.8) from LINQ to find intersecting tags:

```
var result = model
    .Select(post => new Post
    {
        Title = post.Title,
        Tags = post.Tags.Intersect(tags, new TagEqualityComparer()).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Might be overkill for your scenario, but since you mentioned *intersection* I didn't think it would be a bad idea to post this.

If the `Tag` class gets bigger with more properties, then the above solution could be beneficial also, since you can just update the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods and pass the comparer around instead.

You can also reuse the same comparer for other LINQ methods such as `Except`, `OrderBy`, `SequenceEqual` etc., Which could be beneficial as well.